# Show that function is monotonic: $f(x)=x^{2}-2x-1$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, monotone-functions

In homework I'm supposed to show that this function is monotonic, or if it's monotonic at all:

$$f(x)=x^{2}-2x-1$$

I did it like that but I'm not sure at all if it's the correct way to do, I need confirmation or my teacher is mad I did wrong please:

$$f'(x)=0$$

$$f'(x)=2x-2$$

$$0=2x-2|+2$$

$$2x=2|:2$$

$$x=1$$

Because $1>0$ the function is monotonic increasing?

Please say if it's correct I don't want teacher makes me bad in class and other laugh again... I need present tomorrow in class :(

Comment: This function can't be monotonic, for $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x)= +\infty$...

Comment: If a function is increasing what values will its derivative take? Draw a picture!

Comment: Maybe you have to show that it is monotonic in some particular domain?

Comment: Note that $f'(x) = 2(x-1) $ is positive for $x>1$ and negative for $x<1$.

Comment: No, I need show if function is monotonic.

Comment: $|\operatorname{\circ}$ means "do $\circ$ to both sides"? That's a useful notation

Comment: It helps to know that the graph of a quadratic is a parabola.

Comment: Yes this is operation thing we always must use if not use we get no points for work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For monotonicity (increasing at least) we need the derivative positive everywhere. This is not the case. You should test that when $x > 1$ (note the strict inequality here) the derivative is positive. When $x < 1$ the derivative is negative. So, $f$ is monotone on either $(1, \infty)$ or $(-\infty, 1)$.

You did it, just needed a little more. No worries, all shall be well.

Comment: You say we need derivative positive everywhere. What if we had $f'(x)=x^{2}$? This would be monotonic right? Because not can be negative.

Comment: This corresponds to a function $f(x) = x^3 + C$ where $C$ is any real constant. Draw a picture of this function and you see that it is increasing everywhere.

Comment: Ok you say is monotone only in these intervals. I need say that or I can directly say NO FUNCTION ISN'T MONOTONIC?

Comment: Correct. No need for caps, please. The typical definition for monotone is to be nonincreasing or nondecreasing everywhere. To get brownie points you can mention monotonicity in an interval.

Comment: Ok then I say this in presentation :D Thank you much all for write me!

Answer (score 1):

The function isn't monotonic:

$$f(0)=-1,\\f(1)=-2,\\f(2)=-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x^2-2x-1=(x-1)^2-2.$$

We can shift the independent variable by $1$ without changing the monotonic character of the function.

$$g(x):=f(x+1)=x^2-2.$$

This function is *even* ($g(x)=g(-x)$), so it cannot be monotonic (if there is an increasing section, by symmetry there is a decreasing section).

---

Note that

$$0<a<b\implies a^2<b^2$$ because you may multiply the respective sides of two inequalities when the terms are positive. And

$$a<b<0\implies0<-b<-a\implies a^2>b^2.$$

So $x^2$ is decreasing to $x=0$, then increasing.

By shifting, $(x-1)^2$ is decreasing to $x=1$ then increasing, and so is $(x-1)^2-2$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is not monotonic in $\mathbb{R}$, it is a U-shaped function with minimum point at $x = 1$. It is monotonic in the intervals $[ - \infty, 1[$ and $]1 , +\infty]$.

Don't worry your teacher would be proud of you.

Answer (score 0):

This function can't be monotonic, for $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x)= +\infty$... You can say (studying the derivative like you did) that for $x=1$ you have a minimum, than the function will be monotonic decreasing in $(-\infty, 1]$ and increasing in $[1, +\infty)$.

Comment: How do you know so fast that this is minimum? Possible without second derivative? Please say.

Comment: First derivative test: when the derivative goes negative-zero-positive, we have a minimum.

Comment: So I make table, I have value x=1. So if at x=0 is negative and at x=2 positive, it's minimum right? This what you say?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. This can be found in your text.

Answer (score 0):

Note you can solve this without calculus.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Then $$f(x + \epsilon) = (x + \epsilon)^2 -2(x + \epsilon) -1$$

$$= x^2 +2\epsilon x + \epsilon^2 - 2x - 2\epsilon -1 $$

thus $$f(x+\epsilon) - f(x) = (x^2 - x^2) +(-2x +2x)+(-1+1) +  \epsilon^2-2\epsilon+2x\epsilon$$
$$=\epsilon(2x-2+\epsilon)$$

This difference is positive when $x>1$ and negative when $x<1$.